# how to use hibernate with with Axis2

Tags: hibernate, apache-axis

I want to use Hibernate with Axis2, so that I can get data from  my database using hibernate and use that date in my webservice.
How to load hibernate configuration inside the axis2. 
If anyone has any information on this please share.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Steps
1.create a web service class and method as usual
2.create method with all parameter (Hibernate mapping class attribute.)..and inside the method create an object of your mapping class and put all the setter and form there call the hibernate add, delete , update (CRUD)
3.create the service...

note: cannot pass object in the method...since the Soap is Xml that use prototype to pass attribute not object.